# Multiple dynamic timers

Tags: c#, timer

I am working on a project where I need to let the user create one (or more) timers to fire off an event.
The user is supposed to define variables such as if the timer should be active and how often the timer will fire along with some other variables of what will happen when the timer is fiering.

All these variables are stored in a dictionary (Disctionary) where the object holds all the variables the user has set and the string is the name that the user has chosen for this timer.

I then want my program to loop through this dictionary and search for all objects which has the variable t_Active set to true (this I have already achieved).
What I need help with figuring out is the follwoing:
When it detects the variable, and if it's set to true, I need the program to see if there is already a timer created for this.
If it isn't, it should create one and set the relevant parameters for the timer.
The two variables t_num and t_period should decide the interval of the timer.
t_num is an int and t_period is a string which will be set to either minutes, hours or days.

Combining t_num with 60000 (minutes), 3600000 (hours) or 86400000 should give the corrct interval.

But how would I go on about programatically create a timer for each user-defined active object?
And how do I get the program to detect wether or not a timer has already been created?

I have been searching both here and on google, but so far I haven't come across something that makes sense to me.
I am still learning C#, so what make sense to you guys may not neccessarilly make sense to me yet. :)

I hope I have explaned what I need good enough, please do ask me to clarify if you don't get me.

Edit:

Maybe I should also mention that the mentioned dictionary will also be saved to an XML file to that the user can pick up all the settings they made at any time.

Edit 2:

@hatchet I am wondering wether or not this will work.
I have tried to make it work, but are bumping in to some difficultied (because I lack the experience and don't fully understand your pseudo-code. I am getting errors, a few that I could sovle, and a few that I couldn't. (I didn't expect fully working code, don't worry)).

Also, the user should be able to modify the timer.
In the mainform, there's a few textboxes and three buttons.
The form is used to send messages.
The user can choose to manually send their message, to add the message to a timer, or to edit the timer.

When the user hits the manual button, the messages goes out to all receivers once.
If the add the message to a timer, a new subform pops up, where they are able to set the following details:
string Name (of timer)
DateTime Start_date
CheckBox Ending
DateTime End_date
NumericUpDown Seconds (minimum value of 15 minutes)
Combobox Minutes, Hours, Days
Checkbox Active

When the user adds the message to a timer, the TimerSettings gets in to the dictionary as sting,Object (my custom object cointaing all the details).

If they hit the modify button on the main form, it is thought that before the subform is opened, the program looks for the correcponding timer (the mainform has a combobox with all added timers), stops the timer and then opens the subform to let the user edit the details.

On the subform is also a delete button so that the user can delete the timer.

When adding or modifying the timer, mainform is catching it and writes the changes to the XML file and the combobox.
And here is where it should look if there's already a timer for this message and create on of there isn't, or restart the timer if there are.

I am not sure how I should make your solution work for this though.
THe procedure of sending the messages takes anything from 30 seconds to 5 minutes depending on the number of receivers (can't be more than 42 (the program is an interface to another program which doesn't allow for more than 42 receivers)).

I understand that several timers could be an issue, but I doubt that any user would need more than max 10 timers anyway, so there could be a built in limitation of, lets say, 15 timers.

Comment: You only need one timer, set to fire when the closest of all the different targets is scheduled to happen. It can handle them all.

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish what I need with your suggestion.
Lets say I have a timer fiering off every one second, how do I determine which event is to fire if the user have, lets say 5 events, all of them set to fire off at completely different times?

Could you offer a pseudo example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of pseudo code C#, to convey the idea. I have done this same thing, but there are enough little details that are different, that pasting that code would be confusing. So off the top of my head, this semi-code will hopefully be close enough to real code to show you what I meant by my comment to your question.

Say you have a class like this

```
public delegate void Work();

public class TimedThing {
    public int IntervalSecs;
    public DateTime NextFiring;
    public event Work OnWork;        
}
```

Then you have a controller class

```
public class TimedGroup {
    TimedThing[] things;
    System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public TimedGroup() {
        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        this.timer.AutoReset = false;
        this.timer.Elapsed += TimerFired;
    }
            ...
    // some methods for adding and removing TimerThings
            ...
    public void Start() {
        this.timer.Interval = 1; // just to get things started
        this.timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    public void Stop() {
        this.timer.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void TimerFired(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        // let's have timer fire at least as frequently as every 5 minutes
        // if we need to have it fire sooner than that, it will get set below
        DateTime next = now.AddMinutes(5); 
        foreach(var thing in this.things) {
            if (thing.nextFiring <= now) {
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(thing));
                thing.NextFiring = thing.NextFiring.AddSeconds(thing.IntervalSeconds);
                // or maybe this is more appropriate
                // thing.NextFiring = Now.AddSeconds(thing.IntervalSecs);
            }
            if (thing.NextFiring < next) next = thing.NextFiring;
        }
        // set the timer to fire whenever the next soonest work needs to be done
        this.Timer.Interval = (next - now).TotalMilliseconds;
        this.Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void DoWork(TimedThing thing) {
        thing.Work();
    }
}
```

There are likely details though that have to be dealt with, although many of these details have to be dealt with whether you are using a timer for every thing, or a single timer for them all. For instance, what if the work for a thing normally takes 10 seconds, but occasionally it may take 60 seconds, and they have a time interval set for 45 seconds. Sometimes the next firing will want to run that work again, although the previous work started on the previous firing is still running. That may or may not be desirable, depending on what kind of work these things are doing. If it isn't desirable, you have to add some monitoring of the tasks that get spawned so you will know if you need to skip doing the work because the previous work isn't done yet. Another thing is coding a graceful winding down. When you set the timer.Enabled to false (or timer.Stop()...which is the same thing), there is a brief period of time where the timer event can still fire, even though you stopped the timer (see [Why does System.Timer.Timer still fire events when Enabled is set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455393/why-does-system-timer-timer-still-fire-events-when-enabled-is-set-to-false)). That can make for some weird behavior/bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well timers will scale with that approach.  It might be worth investigating other approaches to managing these events.  As @hatchet just made a comment, you could have 1 timer for the next event.. with that approach, you can set up the next one when it runs.

Another possibility is using a database and a timer that runs every <small time period> which executes all actions with due time stamps.

Comment: This sounds very much like the "Database as a Queue" anti-pattern.