# How to run/cancel an event if text is not changed during a certain amount of time? C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run a method after a certain time if a text is not changed and if it is changed then I wont the "timer" to restart.

This is what I am currently working with.

First I have a while loop that constantly calls my `TextChanged`event if any text has been added:

```
TextChanged(result); //result is the added text
```

Then I recieve it here:

```
string result = "";

public async void TextChanged(string text)
{
   result = result + text;
}
```

And I keep adding text to the string. Now what I am trying to achieve is if new text does not get added within 5 seconds I want to run a function with the end result of the text:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgsMethod> textChanged;

textChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgsMethod(result));
```

Now I am trying to put all the pieces together here and what I tried to do that I thought would work in theory (but a bad solution) was this code:

```
    string result = "";
    int timercheck = 0;

    public async void TextChanged(string text)
    {
        if (result.Split(' ').Last() == text)
        {
            if (timercheck == 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                timercheck = 1;
                TextChanged (null);
            }

            else if (timercheck == 1)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                timercheck = 2;
                TextChanged (null);
            }

            else if (timercheck == 2)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                timercheck = 3;
                TextChanged (null);
            }

            else
            {
                textChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgsMethod(result));
                TextChanged (null);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            result = result + text;
        }

    }
```

So what I tried to do was to recall the method to see if new text has been added but this bad solution gives me a crash because it gets called like 20 times in matter of seconds.

How can run an event if a text is not changed during a certain amount of time? I read something about `System.Timers` that might be the thing I am looking for?

Comment: create a Timer that runs for X seconds.   Every time the text change event fires, reset the Timer.  When the timer finally fires you know that X seconds have gone by with no text changes.

Comment: made it work with System.Timers but there is a bug that makes the event refire even though it is set to false. Is there any other Timer-library that works in Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the Timer and not your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455393/why-does-system-timer-timer-still-fire-events-when-enabled-is-set-to-false i have similiar issues like this. there seems to be a solution but if there is another timer out there that works straight out of the box i would prefer that